# Trying to duel boot linux/windows with each OS on a different HD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

I'll try to do my best to explain the situation. So I want to boot linux/windows, but duel boot not just boot from the current hd.

Something I noticed when I went into the BIOS settings. I'm not sure if this is something that is causing this issue or what, but I can only one have one of the HD in the boot priority list at a time.

I have to go to boot options and go to `Hard Drive BBS Priorities` to switch to the other hard drive. Now when I switch the other one can't be in the main Boot Priority list. I have no clue as to why it is doing this.

I was told by a friend and through some research a "grub" screen should appear when I boot. What is a grub screen and could the reason above be why I don't see it?

Comment: You only need your BIOS to boot a single disk (I'm assuming legacy; not uefi) as a disk is booted by loading and running the first sector (512 bytes) of the disk (this sector is called MBR or *master boot record*). GRUB is a boot-loader+menu and consists of a few parts; the first goes on your MBR; subsequent parts can boot any disk but must be located on one disk (usually in your /boot partition).  I'd suggest doing research; open a search engine (eg. startpage.com) & something like "what is grub" & the first entry was a wikipedia entry for "grub".  Also this site is for **Ubuntu** questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I installed ubuntu with windows it gave an option for dual boot. It would flash on the screen and allow you to choose which operating system to start. I believe you have an installation issue. Try reinstalling ensure you choose the dual boot options. All else fails you can load ubuntu on a USB drive and run it from there.